# Best way to save huge collection of records to XLS

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I am using a MySql database containing milions of records. I need to be able to save a large amount of records to a XLS (and PDF) file. Which is the best solution?

I tried something like this: [Export very large data to Excel file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file)
 but it uses too much RAM (about 6go).

Also, I tried to save the records to a datatable and then to write them to a file using RDLC. I still have the RAM problem, this time is worse.

I'm out of ideas. I tried to export 1mil records without succes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to simply process the rows in batches instead of processing all rows at once?

Comment: I've done this before, splitting to a new Excel sheet each time it hits 65536 rows. Perhaps consider that as an option.

Comment: Yes bassfader, I did that, doesn't work. I used the Davy C ideea, it's working a little bit better but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

XLS has a limitation of 65k rows and newer Excel formats have a limit just over 1m rows.
https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx

If your "1mil" records is an underestimation by even 10%, that format will not work.  If you are trying to transfer the data to another system, you may want to try CSV or something like that - but if PDF was one of your options, I'm really not sure what you're trying to do.

That issue aside, pick some column(s) that are repetitive (e.g., AccountID) and run the export (to the CSV) in a loop, once for each AccountID.  This will break the processing into more-managable chunks.  You can then append the CSVs together at the end, if you really have a need for them to all be in one file.

Comment: I know the limits of the Excel files but it needs to be written to the file even if the file will not pe openable. Also, I need to write all those records to a PDF file but if I can find a solution to create a XLS file with more than 1mil recods then maybe I could create a PDF file in the same way. In this moment i don't have a good solution to write even 1mil records to a excel file.

Comment: Is PDF the end goal and XLS is only meant as a step in that direction?

Comment: Kind of. I need to generate some reports is CSV, Excel and PDF. CSV it's working fine but the others are just impossible.

Comment: Excel will open a CSV all by itself, so if you've got CSV working (a la @bassfader), you're on the right track and not up against the XLS size limits. Heck, rename it to XLS - it will either be just as unopenable or Excel might get wise and open it as CSV for you.

For PDF, I'm guessing you want something that looks table-like for a million rows on thousands of pages?  Like CSV, HTML is just text so might not be too hard to spit out as an intermediate step and use a Print to PDF tool...but I don't know about thousands of pages, especially if you're already running out of RAM.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I create the CSV right from MySql and it doesn't use that much ram. I can't export PDF directly from MySql (maybe I can export Excel) and if I create datatables all the RAM is used very quick. I'm trying to find a method to extract the data and put it in a file (let's say the extension doesn't matter) with the lowest RAM consumption. It's tricky but I think there is a solution for that. It's more a research than a task.

Comment: Instead of DataTables, have you considered a forward-only DataReader?  That could/should take up a LOT less memory as it's not all read at once.

Comment: Already tried. But when the file is open for writing all the RAM is used by it.

Comment: Can you write to separate files, like bassfader suggested?  Maybe in the DataReader loop, stop one file and start another based on the next CustomerID or ProductID or whatever you have?  You can always concatenate text files (or even PDFs) later.

Comment: I thought about that but... let's say I will create 10 XLS. When I want to concatenate them I need to open files two by two and write from each one to another. In this case it's not the same situation as above? For last two files I will have a huge one (final document) and a smaller one, both opened in the same time. Earlier I had only one huge document (which eats all my ram) and a DataReader. Now i have a reader (from a XLS this time) and the same file. Somehow I need to open just a small part of that huge document.

Comment: Remember that the XLS will be unreadable.  Whoever is asking for that must not be expecting to actually be able to read it.

CSVs can be easily concatenated and most PDF converters/printers allow for concatenation.  PDFs are very commonly huge so that tool should expect large file concatenation.

Comment: I know that it will be unreadable. My present problem is that I can't even reach the limit (~1mil records).

Comment: Because it's running out of memory?  Are you using DataReader now and the open file is just too big?  Have you considered an XML Spreadsheet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) which could, again, be saved in chunks and concatenated together later?

Comment: Yes, because it's running out of memory. I am using DataReader and the file becomes so big until the system is crashing (windows starts to kill processes in order to free more ram). I tried using OpenXml which I think use XML spreadsheets in order to create the file.

Comment: The only thing left to try, then, is to split up the file.  Put an ORDER BY in your SQL statement as as the DataReader hits a new value for that column, close down the file and create a new one.  We haven't yet gotten to the part where you want to convert to PDF but can't worry about the memory usage there until we have something to work with in this step.